# Original baking time based on ingredients already being warm to hot

Tags: cooking-time

How do I convert cooking time when original recipe assumes prep to oven ingredients already warm? I've put the casserole together and refrigerated overnight.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

I think there is only one possible answer, if we don't know your recipe, volume, oven characteristics and cookery.

Stick a probe thermometer in the middle of the casserole and heat it at the normal temperature until it is bubbly, browned and internal temperature reading at least 140F˚ / 60C˚.

Comment: Get one of these things or similar: http://cmm-onlinesales.com/meat-heat/